# XML Difference in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xmldiff

I have a two XML files like one is old XML file and another one is new XML file. I want to print difference between files

I want output like this:

- if content changed Degree to B.com it is a updated data
- if attribute changed consider as a newly added data

Example output:

```
UPDATED DATA:
in the "joindef" in the entry name = 
"Hardware" in the option name ="Graduation" content Degree was changed to B.com
NEWLY ADDED DATA:
in the "join_def" entry name "VHDL" is added.
in the "join_def" in the entry name "Software" option name "Location" is added.
```

OLDXML FILE:

```
<ls_new>#mainblock

<new_def>#subblock1
............
............
............
</new_def>

<join_def>
    <entry name="Software">
        <option name="Graduation">B.tech</option>
        <member>year=2011</member>
        <option name="PostGraduation">M.tech</option>
        <option name="JobNum">50</option>
    </entry>
    <entry name="Hardware">
        <option name="Graduation">Degree</option>
        <member>year=2011</member>
        <option name="PostGraduation">MCA</option>
        <option name="JobNum">100</option>
    </entry>
</join_def>
<old_def>#subblock3
............
............
............
</old_def>

</ls_new>
```

NEWXML FILE:

```
<ls_new>#mainblock

<new_def>#subblock1
............
............
............
</new_def>

<join_def>
    <entry name="Software">
        <option name="Graduation">B.tech</option>
        <member>year=2011</member>
        <option name="PostGraduation">M.tech</option>
        <option name="JobNum">50</option>
        <option name="Location">india</option>
    </entry>
    <entry name="Hardware">
        <option name="Graduation">B.com</option>
        <member>year=2011</member>
        <option name="PostGraduation">MCA</option>
        <option name="JobNum">100</option>
    </entry>
    <entry name="VHDL">
        <option name="Graduation">B.com</option>
        <member>year=2011</member>
        <option name="PostGraduation">MCA</option>
        <option name="JobNum">150</option>
    </entry>
</join_def>
<old_def>#subblock3
............
............
............
</old_def>

</ls_new>
```

I am new to Perl. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: It is fine if your English isn't perfect: we will make allowances for you and do our best to understand. But please don't make it more difficult than it needs to be by making up abbreviations. I have never seen *b/w* used to mean *between* before

Comment: It would help very much if the example output you show corresponded to the input XML data. Neither `Acro Read` nor `LS_SYSTEM` appear anywhere in the input data, so how does it get to the output file?

Answer (score -1):

There are modules available in Perl for you to convert XML data to a Perl hash.

Perl is extremely XML-friendly given the number of modules avaible in CPAN for that.

In this case I would use the [XML::Hash](http://search.cpan.org/~braceta/XML-Hash-0.95/lib/XML/Hash.pm) module.

Given that you now have two hashes with key value pairs.

You can iterate over the old hash keys, searching for the values in the new hash and print the results as needed.